Amazon Sponsored Brand API's returning a report status of "Failure", "Report generation has failed."
Using the following Amazon Sponsored Brand API endpoints:
"/v2/hsa/adGroups/report",
"/v2/hsa/keywords/report"
The status of the requested report returns the following:
"status": "FAILURE",
"statusDetails": "Report generation has failed. Please try again later."
This failure status occurs consistently for several different amazon advertising accounts all in the North America region (amazon.com) and for recent report dates less than 1 week from the current date.
I have tried rerunning the requests again later and these return the same error consistently when requesting again for the same account, time frame and region.
I have also tried varying the report date requested and for the same account and region, the error still occurs consistently.
This issue has only occurred in the last week and I have not encountered it before.
Thanks!
